# TypeScript - Reduce with a return type that has only optional fields

Tags: typescript, types, reduce

I'm struggling to make TypeScript compiler satisfied with my code.

I have a type that has only optional fields, e.g.:

```
interface UserData {
  email?: string;
  phone?: string;
  //...
}
```

and I have reduce function that formats some data into `UserData` format:

```
type FieldValue = string | number | boolean;

interface RawData {
 fieldName: string;
 fieldValue: FieldValue;
}

function formatField(value: FieldValue): string {
  // format the value and return string
  return `formatted-${value}`;
}

function format(rawDataList: RawData[]): UserData {
  return rawDataList.reduce<UserData>((userData, rawData) => {
      // COMPILER ERROR -> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'
      userData[rawData.fieldName as keyof UserData] = formatField(rawData.fieldValue);

      return userData;
    },
    {}
  );
```

However the field assignment always complains with `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'`. Am I missing something?

Comment: [I'm not seeing that error](https://tsplay.dev/wOz8lW), do I need to change any of the flags in the playground to get the error?

Comment: @Kosmetika I think you should remove `as keyof UserData` in order to get an error. It is unclear a bit

Comment: Sorry, it indeed works in playground, probably smth with project setup

Answer (score 2):

`rawData.fieldName` is a string and it can't be used as an index for `UserData`.
Because `UserData` allows you to use only either `email` or `phone`.

You can do this:

```js
interface UserData {
  email?: string;
  phone?: string;
  //...
}

type FieldValue = string | number | boolean;

interface RawData {
  fieldName: 'email' | 'phone'; // <--------------------- fix
  fieldValue: FieldValue;
}

function formatField(value: FieldValue): string {
  // format the value and return string
  return `formatted-${value}`;
}

function format(rawDataList: RawData[]): UserData {
  return rawDataList.reduce<UserData>((userData, rawData) => {
    userData[rawData.fieldName] = formatField(rawData.fieldValue);
    return userData;
  }, {})
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdoBE5jsgbwChlkIBbOYAGwH4AuZdMKUAcwG4TkAHACwD2ICAyYt2XUgHopAOnlEAvkSJgAnjxQAxYBGoATAGpxqAVxQBeMaxBtkAH2QhT5AEbQHyVwIHUIcEC4iUEhYRBQAJTgAdxw8Qm4YXQMAOThyCEYAcgoqaizPLP4hCCzJZCS9IxNzRh0q4zMILmUiGFMQBDBgIQqBKEoweoMACgA3GszkYeqmgEpGZhs7YmkpPoHcZDA%20FAmm5AD9ZCgIMFMoEGt2blPzy%20QAAxh%20wch9AFoAEgJ980VHi0VO1Ot1ei9NmARlAYnE4AAZYDMRhRWK4OAAbQAugs0JgoHCEqQ7hcrjC0XhEcxZKd9KYkAAeDDYdEAPhGI1M%20LhABoTrD0XNkBZWUTSMguSy8BjyXDZJVUukIFjhRtBjNoQK8PLkrNzHNysSzqSJdz0eVFHyCIo5kogA)

Comment: I'm confused, the OP's code works, doesn't it? Or is there some flag or something that I need to set to make it not work?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder there is an error on the last line of OP's code. Extra parentheses ). Once you fix it, you will see original error

Comment: I did fix it, in the playground in [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69910995/typescript-reduce-with-a-return-type-that-has-only-optional-fields/69911238?noredirect=1#comment123581207_69910995). I don't get an error in that playground.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Try to remove `as keyof UserData`

Comment: Well, yeah, but the OP didn't say "if I remove `as keyof UserData`." It would be **really** good if they'd come back and clarify what the issue is.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, yes, OP did not say it :(

Comment: Still, if their goal is to remove that type assertion (often a worthy goal), this shows them how to do it, so... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder off topic, why do you write `they` ? I'm not native speaker. Is this  because it might be unpolite to write `he/she` ?

Comment: @captain-yossarian `they` is a gender neutral pronoun, and can be used when the subject's preferencial pronouns are not known. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they)

Comment: Yes. "They" as the "gender indeterminate/irrelevant" pronoun goes back hundreds of years in English (1345, says the Oxford English Dictionary). Using "he" when you don't know only became common in the late 1700's / early 1800's and is, well, a bit exclusionary. In the 1970s/80s people started promoting "he/she" but it's clunky. :-) Now, here in 2021, we also have non-binary people who use "they" in preference to "he" or "she". So when I don't know, I default to "they."

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks you for thorough explanation. I had a feeling that using `he/she` might cause a problem for me. Good to know